# Understanding railties dependencies - bundler "could not find compatible"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, bundler

So, this error from bundler throws me off, I can't see what's not compatible:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
  coffee-rails was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
    railties (< 5.2.x, >= 4.0.0)

  font-awesome-rails (~> 4.6) was resolved to 4.7.0.1, which depends on
    railties (< 5.1, >= 3.2)

  rails (~> 5.0.7) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
    railties (= 5.0.7)

  rails-i18n (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
    railties (< 6, >= 5.0)

  sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
    railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
```

Anybody care to lay it out for me?

Comment: try removing your Gemfile.lock file and bundling again

Comment: Thanks, it made no difference. And that's not really my question. I wonder how to interpret the text above, since in my head the text says these gems are compatible while claiming they aren't.

Comment: Fair point, it looks like 5.0.7 should be valid

Comment: is that the full error? Can you provide the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Had this kind of issue in the past upgrading from 4.2 because I had "quiet_assets" on the Gemfile, which is not supported by 5.x, maybe one of the gems on your Gemfile is not supported and causing that.